# When does a CALayer have a presentationLayer?

Tags: swift, macos, calayer, appkit, presentation-layer

I was working with CALayers and I want to retrieve some information about the state of a sublayer of my layer while an animation is running. Now I know I can retrieve the information from the sublayer's presentation layer by calling `mySublayer.presentation()` and accessing the returned layer's properties.

However the return value is an optional value and does actually return `nil` relatively often. In my particular case the call happens inside of the `layoutSublayers()` of my layer (the superlayer of the layer who's information I want).

That's why I was wondering: When does a layer have a presentation layer and when does it not have one?
Unfortunately I could't really find anything on this in Apple's documentation.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you miss this in the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410744-presentationlayer)? `While an animation is in progress, you can retrieve this object and use it to get the current values for those animations.`

Comment: AS you did point out, I am aware that it exists during animation. It just seemed to me that sometimes during animation I still got nil. I might have missed something in my code though, so I will check again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> When does a layer have a presentation layer

When it's part of the render tree. A layer is *always* rendered onscreen as its presentation layer.

The reason you're getting `nil` is that you're looking at the presentation layer from inside an early `layoutSublayers()`. That is exactly when the layer does *not* have a presentation layer; we're in the middle of configuring the render tree for the first time.

Here's some testing code that will show you what's going on:

```
func delay(_ delay:Double, closure:@escaping ()->()) {
    let when = DispatchTime.now() + delay
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when, execute: closure)
}
class MyLayer : CALayer {
    override func layoutSublayers() {
        print("here1")
        if let subs = self.sublayers {
            for lay in subs {
                print(lay.presentation() as Any)
            }
        }
        super.layoutSublayers()
        print("here2")
        if let subs = self.sublayers {
            for lay in subs {
                print(lay.presentation() as Any)
            }
        }
    }
}
class MyView : UIView {
    override class var layerClass: AnyClass { return MyLayer.self }
}
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let lay = CALayer()
        lay.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        lay.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 10, height: 10)
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(lay)
        print(lay.presentation() as Any)
        delay(1) {
            print(lay.presentation() as Any)
            print("let's try rerendering")
            self.view.setNeedsLayout()
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}
```

Set the view controller's view to be a MyView in the storyboard, and launch. We get `nil` repeatedly until we reach the `delay` call. Now the layer is part of the render tree, so now and on the next round of layout, the layer has a presentation layer.

Another interesting thing (left as an exercise for the reader) is to animate the layer. The layer acquires a *different* presentation layer during animation, and yet *another* presentation layer when the animation is over. It's very important to keep this in mind when working this closely with a layer; its presentation layer is not a constant single object — and it is *copied* from the original layer each time it is created anew. (Boy, was I confused before I realized that.)